# UnderscoreJS - For loop the length of an array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Say I have an array `myArray` of some length `N`. I want to loop `N`th time. In pure Javascript, that would be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {}
```

Is there a way to also do this in UnderscoreJS? I know I can use `_.each` in the following way:

```
_.each(myArray, function(a) {
});
```

but I don't particularly want to loop through the entries. There is no reason why i want to do this. This is purely a thought experiment and I was just wondering if there is a way of doing this!

Comment: What's wrong with `_.each`? Doesn't it call the function `N` times?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `_.each`. It does run `N` times. But I was just wondering if I could create the exact same thing as the `for` loop in Javascript (i.e. just loop with the index, not the actual item).

Comment: `_.times(myArray.length, function() {...})`?

Comment: @univerio: That's pretty close to an answer. A documentation reference, some explanation, and maybe an example is all it needs.

Comment: @univerio, this works perfectly. If you post it, I can vote it.

Comment: the index is the 2nd argument to the each() callback anyway, you can just ignore the first argument...

Comment: @dandavis, yes I understand that. This is purely a thought experiment, and I just wanted to see if it is possible to do this without getting the argument itself.

Comment: So you want to do a noop n times, where n is the length of an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`_.times()`](http://underscorejs.org/#times) function to execute a callback `n` times:

```
_.times(myArray.length, function(i) {...})
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can use `each` and just use the index and ignore the actual entries:

```
_.each(myArray, function(a, i) {
   ... do something with i but not a ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but as I said,  I know I can do that.  I was looking to see if there is a way only get the index. Please see the accepted the answer to what I was looking for.

Comment: It wasn't clear that you knew about the iterator function getting the index as a second argument, since you didn't have such an argument in your example code.  That's the part I was trying to get across in case you weren't aware of it and thought you would have to keep your own counter or something, which might influence your desire not to go that route.